# Group by on clickhouse with condition less than grouped column

Tags: sql, group-by, clickhouse

I have part of sql code :

```
select   
    ,inst_date
    ,country
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 0 then id end)) as event_0
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 1 then id end)) as event_1
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 2 then id end)) as event_2
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 3 then id end)) as event_3
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 4 then id end)) as event_4
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 5 then id end)) as event_5
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 6 then id end)) as event_6
    ,count (distinct (case when (event_day - inst_date) <= 7 then id end)) as event_7
from t1
all left join 
(
    select distinct id
         , toDate(event_date) as event_day
         , 1 as event
    from events
) as events_
using id
where (event_day - inst_date) between 0 and 7
group by inst_date
    ,country ;
```

and I see my data :

| inst_date | country | event_0 | event_1 | event_2 | event_3 | event_4 | event_5 | event_6 | event_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 10 | 11 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 14 | 14 |

but I want to collect this data like

| inst_date | country | date_difference | events_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 0 | 10 |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 1 | 11 |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 2 | 11 |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 3 | 12 |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 4 | 13 |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 5 | 14 |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 6 | 14 |
| 2020-12-01 | us | 7 | 14 |

at t1 table - list of id's with country and inst date. At events table - date of event by id

Comment: it looks like a simple cumulative sum? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5DarrayCumSum https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#arraycumsumfunc-arr1 https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#runningaccumulate

Comment: Unfortunately no, if in CASE block was SUM, array cumsum can be used here, but i have to count distinct id's at current period

Comment: i see, https://groups.google.com/g/clickhouse/c/BqE49KuJpw8/m/I9Ymh6axEAAJ

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
select inst_date, country, 
    (event_day - inst_date) as date_difference,
    count(*) as events_count
from t1
all left join (
    select distinct id, toDate(event_date) as event_day, 1 as event
    from events
) as events_ using id
where (event_day - inst_date) between 0 and 7
group by inst_date, country, (event_day - inst_date)
order by inst_date, country, date_difference;
```

I would strongly recommend prefixing all columns in the query with the table they belong to, so the query is unambiguous about the underlying data structures.